# How can I get the mean of multiple columns grouping by two different factors?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to get the mean of a series columns grouping by station but keeping it separated by year.

My data looks something like this

```
+---------+------+-------+------+------+------+
| station | year | month | tmax | tmin | rain |
+---------+------+-------+------+------+------+
| A       | 2006 |     1 |   15 |   15 | NA   |
| A       | 2006 |     2 |   25 |   16 | 4    |
| A       | 2006 |     3 |   30 |   18 | 7    |
| A       | 2006 |     4 |   40 |   18 | 5    |
| A       | 2007 |     1 |   15 |   15 | 6    |
| A       | 2007 |     2 |   25 |   16 | 8    |
| A       | 2007 |     3 |   30 |   18 | 10   |
| A       | 2007 |     4 |   40 |   18 | 3    |
| A       | 2008 |     1 |   15 |   15 | 5    |
| A       | 2008 |     2 |   25 |   16 | 8    |
| A       | 2008 |     3 |   30 |   18 | 1    |
| A       | 2008 |     4 |   40 |   18 | 3    |
| B       | 2006 |     1 |   15 |   15 | NA   |
| B       | 2006 |     2 |   25 |   16 | 4    |
| B       | 2006 |     3 |   30 |   18 | 7    |
| B       | 2006 |     4 |   40 |   18 | 5    |
| B       | 2007 |     1 |   15 |   15 | 6    |
| B       | 2007 |     2 |   25 |   16 |      |
| B       | 2007 |     3 |   30 |   18 |      |
| B       | 2007 |     4 |   40 |   18 |      |
| B       | 2008 |       |      |      |      |
+---------+------+-------+------+------+------+
```

I've tried this, but I feel like I'm completely missing the point and it doesn't get me the output I want

```
t <- NewData %>% group_by(station) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(-station, -year), funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))
```

I want to get something like this as an output

```
+---------+------+------+------+------+
| station | year | tmax | tmin | rain |
+---------+------+------+------+------+
| A       | 2006 |   15 |   15 | NA   |
| A       | 2007 |   25 |   16 | 4    |
| A       | 2008 |   30 |   18 | 7    |
| B       | 2006 |   40 |   18 | 5    |
| B       | 2007 |   15 |   15 | 6    |
| B       | 2008 |   25 |   16 | 8    |
| C       | 2006 |   30 |   18 | 10   |
| C       | 2007 |   40 |   18 | 3    |
| C       | 2008 |   15 |   15 | 5    |
+---------+------+------+------+------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is helpful if you post your data based on output generated by `dput()` , so others can easily load your data into R.

Comment: Thanks Wimpel, I didn't know about dput() and wasn't sure how to do it!

Comment: this works for me on data looking similar ot yours   NewData %>% group_by(station, year) %>% summarise(tmax = mean(tmax, na.rm = TRUE), tmin = mean(tmin, na.rm = TRUE), rain = mean(rain, na.rm = TRUE))

Comment: @ChrisLittler It worked! Thank you so much. I pretty much had it, but I had tried group_by(station) %>%  group_by(year) %>% as separate function, and was using summarise_at(), which I think was somehow was messing with how it grouped the data (I still can't get my head around the logic of dplyr most of the time).
Cheers!